# Using DeleteCases and Map together

Tags: map, pure-function

Given:

```
list1 = {{"a",1},{"b",2},{"c",3}}
```

I would like to delete any pair in list1 that does not have a first element that belongs to list2.

> Example 1: If list2 = {"b"}, Output = {{"b",2}}
>   Example 2: If list2 = {"A","b"}, Output = {{"a",1},{"b",2}}

Here's what I have so far:

```
DeleteCases[list1,{#,_}/; !StringMatchQ[#,list2, IgnoreCase -> True]&].
```

I know this won't work (because StringMatchQ doesn't accept a list of values to compare to as a parameter, which leads me to thinking I need to Map the function above to list2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost got it:

```
list1 = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}};
list2 = {"A", "b"};

test = StringMatchQ[#, Alternatives @@ list2, IgnoreCase -> True] &;

Cases[list1, {_?test, _}]
```

> ```
> {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}}
> ```

A key element is clearly [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html).
I used `Cases` rather than `DeleteCases` as that seemed simpler to me.

---

The first part of my post is in direct answer to your question.  Summary: use `Alternatives`, not `Map`.

Borrowing from belisarius' answer, if one is going to use `ToLowerCase` I propose this:

```
Pick[list1, list1[[All, 1]], Alternatives @@ ToLowerCase @ list2]
```

If some of the elements of `list1` are not all lower case then:

```
Pick[list1, ToLowerCase @ list1[[All, 1]], Alternatives @@ ToLowerCase @ list2]
```

Answer (score 5):

Also:

```
list1 = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}};
f[list1_, list2_] := Select[list1, MemberQ[ToLowerCase /@ list2, #[[1]]] &]
f[list1, {"A", "b"}]

(* {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}} *)
```

Comment: That's nice too.  I'd +1 but I'm out of votes for the day. (Remind me tomorrow.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks :)I turned it to CW so neither of us will need to remember the nuisance :)

Comment: @belisarius - Very nice, thanks!